# Does lesser celestial totem proc on Fire God's Blessing and similar feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature, rage

Does the rage power [lesser celestial totem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/celestial-totem-lesser-su/) increases the healing afforded by the feat [Fire God's Blessing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fire-god-s-blessing/) or by the feat [Glorious Heat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/glorious-heat/)? If so, by how much?

For example, how many hp are healed by a barbarian 8/life oracle 1 that possesses the feat Fire God's Blessing when he deals damage to a foe with his *+1 flaming greatsword*?

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, it does.

The effect of the feat says:

> Whenever she is subject to a spell that cures hit point damage, she heals 1 additional point of damage per caster level. **In the case of non-spell healing effects** (such as channeled energy or lay on hands), she heals a number of additional points equal to the class level of the character performing the magical healing. This does not affect fast healing or regeneration.

Both [Lay on Hands](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin#TOC-Lay-On-Hands-Su-) and [Channel Energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric#Channel_Energy_Su) are supernatural effects that can heal damage. There is nothing on their description that makes them anything special regarding how to classify their effect, neither are classified as [fast healing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Fast-Healing-Ex-) or [regeneration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Regeneration-Ex-) either.

As such, [Glorious Heat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/glorious-heat/) would also benefit from [Lesser Celestial Totem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/celestial-totem-lesser-su/) and heal for:

- **spell level + character's class level** hit points.

For [Fire God's Blessing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fire-god-s-blessing/), the use of the ability seems unintended and stronger than it should be, luckily, it is limited to once per round. But this looks valid from the *rules as written*, and the character would heal for:

- **character's class level + 1** hit points.

However, if both effects are used, i wouldn't let you to get healed twice your level. Because the *source* of the extra healing is the same (the [rage power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/)), and the character would heal for: **character's class level + spell level + 1** hit points.

If the *class* that granted you the [rage power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/) is the barbarian, you should replace *character's class level* by your barbarian levels.

Keep in mind that to qualify for [Fire God's Blessing](http://archivesofnethys.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Fire%20God%27s%20Blessing), the character must worship the **Fire God** (this info was removed from SRD), a deity specific to golarion that is worshipped by certain orc tribes (more info on [Orcs of Golarion](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8fvz?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Orcs-of-Golarion)). The [Belkzen, Hold of Orc Hordes](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9aue?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Belkzen-Hold-of-the-Orc-Hordes) campaign setting book revealed that [this deity](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/DeityDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Sezelrian) is known as [Sezelrian](http://www.pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Sezelrian). Of course, nothing stops your GM from converting this to any other setting.